# AngularJS application architecture

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to Angular but I am quite an experienced developer. So far I have made quite some progress in building my application to work with a CMS. I am a bit lost however on what the 'correct' approach would be to handle data in my model.

This is best described with an example:

Because I am hooking up my angular frontend with a CMS, the routing (pages) exist only in the CMS context. This means that the routing should be dynamic as well. I have managed to get the dynamic routes thing to work, but when I try to do things the right way (actually getting data from a server) I run into some issues...

```
app.config(function($provide, $routeProvider) {
$provide.factory("$routeProvider", function() {
    return $routeProvider;
    });
});
// Load the dynamic routes from the API...
app.run(function($routeProvider, $http, $scope, logger, siteRoutes) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '__views/', controller: 'ContentPageController' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

In other words, I inject a service into my app.run method (siteRoutes) and this one should connect to the API.

So my siteRoutes is a service:

```
cmsModule.service('siteRoutes', function siteRouteFactory(apiConnection, logger)
// SNIP
```

And in this service I inject my generic apiConnection service:

```
cmsModule.factory('apiConnection', ['$q', '$http', '$timeout', 'logger', function apiConnectionService($q, $http, $timeout, logger)
```

What I want is this:

I would like the siteRoutes service to load the data once and not execute the connection every time. I did this in the following way:

```
bla.service('example', function() {
   var service = {
       get: function(apiStuff) { // DO API CONNECT WITH .THEN HERE },
       data: {}
   }
   service.get();
   return service;
}
```

I would like one entry point towards the Api that handles all the $q stuff (my factory) I assumed I need to handle all the .then() stuff in my siteRoutes object, which is what I did.

Now, what happens in my app.run method is that I don't get the siteRoutes object with any data. So I recon I need to do a .then there as well?

But that made me question the entire design of putting all logic in a separate factory for the connection, because I basically like my app to just use the data and have my library deal with the async stuff (if you get what I am saying)...

Hope this is clear.

TL;DR -> How to make your services / factories handle async stuff without making your 'app' deal with it?

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand the bit about _loading dynamic paths_ from the server. Do the names of the path come from the server? Or the code which is to be executed on accessing those paths also served separately? Or are you trying to restrict access to certain paths in certain contexts? Could you expand a bit on how you want to configure the `$routeProvider` in `app.run`?

Comment: What I mean is that the (server side) CMS normally does the routing in this case, meaning the user in the CMS defines pages and things like that. 

So, that being said: what I aiming to do is: http://www.domain.com/bla/blabla.html -> http://www.domain.com/#/bla/blabla.html with the view being bla/blabla.html 

Hope that clarifies things? For now I am just trying to move from server side routing to client side routing.

Answer (score 0):

The templateUrl property can also be a function that takes the url parametes as input.

In the example below all routes will load a template with same name.
Eg. `domain.com/#/blabla.html` will load the view `blabla.html` from the server.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/:templateName',
        {
            templateUrl: function (params) {
                return params.templateName + ".html";
            }
        }
        )
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/main' });
}]);
```